# Component Not Rendering Properly in React when using CSS hover pseudo selector

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

My component is a basic NavBar with different items. When Hovering over the item with the `dopdiwn-items` class, the NavBar should display those items in a block. Instead, only the first item can be seen, with the others being hidden. The same code, when put into plain HTML and CSS on code pen, works as expected. I discovered if I increase the size of the navbar then the items do show as a large block of text. I listed screenshots, and my code below.

CodePen link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dvNvmM

Parent Container:

```
/*Start dependencies*/
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import Picture from '../../components/picture.jsx';
import ShoppingCart from '../../components/shoppingcart.jsx';


import NavBar from '../../components/navbar.jsx';

import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import cart from '../../reducers/index.js';

/*Flag set to know if the client recieved and loaded
Will be set to True once the response from the server
Is loaded and parsed*/
var flag = true;


//Start React class
export default class Products extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {clothingData: 0}
    }



    render(){
    /*if the flag variable is false, server is not done yet retriving 
      data from the DB and parsing it, thus nothing displayed
    */
    if (!flag){ 
    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    );
    }
    //If flag is true (data is ready to be displayed)
    else{
        //console.log(this.state.clothingData[0].path);
        //console.log(this.state.clothingData[0].fileName);
        //console.log(this.state.clothingData);
        return (

            <div>

                <NavBar  />


        <Picture className = "test" src = {this.state.clothingData} onClick = { () => {browserHistory.push('/Product'); }} name = {"joe"} />

      </div>
    );
    }
 }

}
```

JSX:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
export default class NavBar extends Component {
    render(){

    return(


        <ul className="navbar">
         <li className="dropdown">
            <a href="#" className="dropdown-btn">Clothes</a>
            <div className="dropdown-items">  
              <a href="#">Item</a>
              <a href="#">Item</a>
              <a href="#">Item</a>
              <a href="#">Item</a>
            </div>  
        </li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Policies</li>
        <li>How To Rent</li>
        <li>Contact</li>  

         </ul>  

    );
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
/*Main HTML Stylesheet*/


html{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

/*div{
    background:white;
}*/

/********* NavBar Section **********/
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:#B597C3;
}

/* links inside the navigation bar */
.navbar li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .625em 5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* color of links on hover */
.navbar a:hover {
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration: underline;

}

.navbar a.active {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
/* Drop Down Items */
.dropdown-btn {
    float:left;
    font-size: 1.0625em;
    color:white;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow:hidden;

}
.dropdown{

    display: inline-block;

}
.dropdown-items{
    position:absolute;
    display: none;
    margin:0;
    min-width: 10em;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);


}
.dropdown-items a {

    color:white;
    padding: 12px 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;

}


.dropdown:hover .dropdown-items {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}




/********* NavBar Section **********/
```

When Hovered:
[image]

When Hovered w/ increased size: 
[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the link to the said codepen... Also, inspect the elements using DevTools to see what is going on in the DOM.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dvNvmM

Comment: This pen is with the react code and not running into issue you posted http://codepen.io/finalfreq/pen/PpWjBq

Comment: Do you think it could be because this is a component within my parent container ? As opposed to the codepen example which is only rendering that single node

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I think you should not use CSS pseudo selectors with React. I've read questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269669/css-pseudo-elements-in-react) and my conclusion is in React you should handle the `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` events yourself and then keep a component **state** that indicates whether the dropdown should be shown or not.

That is the React way of usually doing things: hook up event handler functions and use the component state. When the handler functions are called, you change the state.

I don't know whether CSS pseudo selectors will work properly with React. You can take a look at this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/reactjs/react-future/issues/13). My guess is that whatever you are trying to do doesn't work with the CSS selectors because React uses a virtual DOM and not the actual DOM. So the CSS would be changing the DOM directly kind of thing? It would be nice if other more knowledgeable people could comment on that.

For now, I think you should follow the React way of doing things. Here is the code for what you are trying to do:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

export default class NavBar extends Component {
  state = {
    showDropdown: false
  }

  renderDropdown() {
    return (
      <div className="dropdown-items">
        <a href="#">Item</a>
        <a href="#">Item</a>
        <a href="#">Item</a>
        <a href="#">Item</a>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="navbar">
        <li
          className="dropdown"
          onMouseEnter={() => this.setState({ showDropdown: true })}
          onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({ showDropdown: false })}
        >
          <a href="#" className="dropdown-btn">Clothes</a>
          {this.state.showDropdown ? this.renderDropdown() : null}
        </li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Policies</li>
        <li>How To Rent</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Keep in mind you should **remove** the CSS rule for the `hover` pseudo selector for the items div, as well as the `display: none` for the dropdown. After doing that, everything should be OK.

Note: I used a property initializer to set up the initial state for the component. Babel should take care of transpiling that. In case that doesn't work, set the initial state in the constructor.

Comment: Well this is more of a styling/presentation issue because it does Render when styled with relative positioning, and another commentor above got it to work in Code Pen, so I think since mines is in a child, thats the issue

Comment: @JustinE.Samuels: Ok, sounds good. I feel like you could get more people interested in the question if you changed the title to include "when using CSS hover pseudo selector". That would also help other people someday in case they came across that issue.