# Trying to convert CSS overlay feature to JSS in React

Tags: css, reactjs, jss

Here is the CSS that I am trying to convert:

```
    .container {
  some CSS in here - figured that out 
}



.overlay {
  some CSS i can convert - not sure on below line
  transition: .5s ease;
}
```

This is the CSS I am most struggling with

```
.container:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Here is my JSS - that is NOT working when it comes to the hover effect:

```
  container: {
    position: 'relative',
    width: '100%',
    '&:hover, &:overlay': {
      height: '100%',
      border: 'solid red'
    }
  },
  overlay: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#008CBA',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    width: '100%',
    height: 0,
    transition: ['.5s', 'ease']
  },
```

I cannot figure out how to convert the .container:hover .overlay  portion?  I search on the JSS playground site and was unable to get anywhere.  I was thinking it was simply a nested problem, but it may be something more obvious.  Just staring at the same problem for too long.

Comment: Inline styles cannot be used to target pseudo-classes or pseudo-elements. You need to use a stylesheet. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269669/css-pseudo-elements-in-react

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS pseudo elements in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269669/css-pseudo-elements-in-react)

Answer (score 1):

You want '&:hover $overlay'