# CSS Pseudo-classes with inline styles in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Now example text with the background will be red color. But I want the class rightElement: after having border-top: color. It should take from const. I don't know how to do that

```
   const color = "red";

   <div className='rightElement' style={{backgroundColor: color} >Example </div>
   rightElement:after

   {
        border-top :color ( From const color )
   }
```

Comment: Requirement i: I need to pass the colour from config file , Example color :red , 1. In the div rightElement I take the config value color:red using this.props.color.But I need className rightElement:after (its a pseudo element) also (I needed from props ).Its possible to do that one using react.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML & CSS

```css
.testAfter::after {
  content: "->"
 }
```

```html
<div class="testAfter">Something</div>
```

We can use ::after and other pseudo code like this in css.

So we need external css to use pseudo code in react.

// test.css

```css
.rightElement::after {
 content: "-> after";
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

// Test.js

```js
import React from 'react';

import './test.css';

class Test extends React.Component {
 render () {
  const color = "red";
  return(
   <div>
    <div className='rightElement' style={{backgroundColor: color}} >Example </div>
   </div>
  )
 }
}

export default Test;
```

Using Inline

```js
render () {
  const color = "red";
  return(
   <div style={{width: '500px', margin: '0 auto', marginTop: '100px'}}>
    <div className='rightElement' style={{backgroundColor: color}} >Example </div>
    <div style={{borderTop: `10px solid ${color}`}}></div>
   </div>
  )
 }
```

The trick here is instant of creating new element via ::after or ::before I create new element by my own.
But creating new element for only styling purpose is not good(Just my option).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to directly access the pseudo element.

However, you could change their style indirectly by adding in a new style element containing new rules.

Try like this to add after css.

```js
const color = "red";


var styleElem = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("style"));

styleElem.innerHTML = "#rightElement:after {border-top: 1px solid "+color+";}";
```

```html
<div id='rightElement' style="background-color: green" >Example </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Syed... i will try like this .

Comment: Super Syed ,Its coming fine .Should we add this one in react code ? because again we are iteration the document .head.appendChild.Is anyway to change as per the react code

Comment: Syed .. any possible solution for react.js .Because the code                                          var styleElem = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("style"));
styleElem.innerHTML = "#rightElement:after {border-top: 1px solid "+color+";}"; look like javascript .Can you do it react based on this???

Answer (score 0):

you looking for this : ? ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties )

```css
:root {
  --my-color: red;
}

.rightElement {
  display: inline-block;
  border-top :5px solid var(--my-color);
}
```

```html
<div class="rightElement" > Example </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See [CSS pseudo elements in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269669/css-pseudo-elements-in-react). It seems that a best practice is to use separate elements in React instead of pseudo-elements. Could you just do this instead?

```
<div className='rightElement' style={{backgroundColor: color}}>
  Example
  <div style={{borderTopColor: color}}></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, FYI your code had a missing close curly brace on style attribute