# How to add hover css style with React.createElement

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm creating a button with `React.createElement`:

```
React.createElement('button', {style: button.key === this.state.customBtnSelected ? customBtnSelected : customBtnUnSelected, onClick: () => {this.handleCustomBtnClick(i)} }, button.label)
```

So the one of the css styles is in the `customBtnUnSelected` variable.

But how do I add css classes for the **hover** state?
So far this isn't working:

```
       const customBtnUnSelected = {
        padding: 12,
        textAlign: "center",
        textDecoration: "none",
        display: "inline-block",
        fontSize: 12, 
        cursor: "pointer",
        backgroundColor: "#CFD4DA",
        border: "1px solid white",
        &:hover: {
          color: "#fff"
        }
      };
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use the :hover, :after, or :before styling to an element, using inline styling.

The only way to achieve that is to use the `<style>` tag, or linking an external `CSS` file to your project.

To insert a style tag, you just place it somewhere in your app. It may be in one of your components, or in the root HTMl file, etc...

```
return (
  <style>{`
    .myButton {
      padding: 8;
      background: black
    }
    .myButton:hover {
      background: grey
    }
  `}</style>
)
```

Then, you can just use the `myButton` class on the `className` prop of your button.

```
<button className='myButton'>Click</button>
```

or

```
React.createElement('button', {className: 'myButton'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of using `React.createElement` or the JSX syntax, React doesn't support selecting pseudo elements with inline styling.

This question has a few answers with a lot more tips that might help you:
[CSS pseudo elements in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269669/css-pseudo-elements-in-react)