# i18n in CSS property "content"

Tags: css, internationalization, less

I'm using Java Web (Spring framework) and LESS as CSS preprocessor.

When applying internationalization on my project, I successfully migrated every message inside JSP and JS code in message.properties files. But I don't know if it's possible to do the same in CSS/LESS code. I really need to do it since there are messages inside a content property.

I already saw the solution using `:lang` selector, but it would be much better if I could import the messages from a central input file.

Comment: you can look for this post: [i18next css content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54785373/6235602)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm late to the party, but I want to point out [an answer to another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29743624) where it turns out that you can use an `attr()` value for the `content` property, referencing an attribute on the selected HTML elements. Shamelessly copying the example from the linked answer, you can write your HTML elements as:

```
<div class="myclass" data-content="My Content"></div>
```

and have the following CSS rule applied to them:

```
.myclass:before {
    content: attr(data-content);
}
```

actually showing "My Content" on the page. That basically means you can now use Spring i18n as:

```
<div class="myclass" data-content="<s:message code="content"/>"></div>
```

and complete your migration to `message.properties` files.

Comment: I actually solved it at the time and forgot to post the answer here. I solved it in the same way you did, but more specific selectors: `.translate-content[data-i18n-before]::before` and `.translate-content[data-i18n-after]::after`

Comment: @Giulio Perfect answer for my problem. Thank you very much.