# How to get a DOM element's ::before content with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, pseudo-element

I want to know whether it is possible to get a DOM element's `::before` content, which was set by CSS3.

I have tried some ways, but I still can't make it, so it's very confusing to me!

```
// https://rollbar.com/docs/

const links = document.querySelectorAll(`ul.image-list a`);

links[0];
// <a href="/docs/notifier/rollbar-gem/" class="ruby">::before Ruby</a>

links[0];
//

links[0].textContent;
//"Ruby"

links[0].innerText;
// "Ruby"

links[0].innerHTML;
// "Ruby"

// ??? links[0]::before;
```

This is the case:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: How does this question not have more votes???

Comment: `getComputedStyle(links[0], '::after').getPropertyValue('content');`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Pass `":before"` as the second parameter to [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle):

```js
console.log(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('p'), ':before').getPropertyValue('content'));
```

```css
p::before,
p::after {
  content: ' Test ';
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

## getComputedStyle() & getPropertyValue()

[image]

> `getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('span.search-box'), '::after').getPropertyValue('content');`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var widthval = 12;
      var style = document.createElement('style');
      style.innerHTML = '.classname::before {content: " ! "; color: red; width: ' + widthval + 'px !important;}';
      document.head.appendChild(style);
    });
```

```html
 <div class="classname">
        Main Title
    </div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).