# Is there way to docuement.getElementById('ELEMENT_ID') to change the content if it has a ::before in the css

Tags: javascript, css

I need to change the content using JavaScript but the element has a ::before in the css

Comment: Without some code (HTML, JavaScript & CSS) & a detailed description of what you're trying to do and what's not working, we're not going to be able to help you

Comment: This one is helpfull pls check,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342065/how-to-get-a-dom-elements-before-content-with-javascript
you can check against any set css property using this and add condition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing your `:before` pseudo element has a property `content` if it's visible, so you could use the [`.getComputedStyle()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```
let style = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#content'),':before')
```

then you have to check your 'content' property

```
var content = style.getPropertyValue("content")
```

and then, you could create a condition with this content value

```
if( content == 'something' ) {
    document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML = "your new content"
}
```