# Changing the 'content' property in a ::before pseudo class

Tags: javascript, css, pseudo-class

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bc2L9uoj/8/)

In my JS I'm trying to access the 'content' property of the dislpay_object::before class.
I need to set the 'content' (text) to the placement of the div on the page.

I've done tons of searching but haven't found anything this in depth on these types of pseudo classes.

```
  .display_object {
  position: absolute;
  border: thin solid black;
  width: 15cm;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.display_object:active::before {
  content: "x,y";
  /*needs to be changed to actual values*/
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
  padding: 1em 3em;
  color: white;
  font-size: .8em;
  bottom: 1.6em;
  left: -1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

How can I reference the .content of  the :active::before through JS, to set it to its current position?

Comment: Ah, I've totally forgotten CSS `attr()` function. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42000085/11695199) in the dup Alex has suggested. @Chiller, that is just what I'd call "unreasonable way" in the context of the mousemove handler.

Comment: I forgot the attr() function too XD, nice catch  @Teemu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via [this answer](http://%09%09%09div.setAttribute('data-before',%60x:%20$%7BmousePosition.x%7D,%20y:%20$%7BmousePosition.y%7D%60);), you can set the `before` pseudo-element's `content` property to an attribute of the parent div by using `attr()`:

```
content: attr(data-before);
```

Then just update that attribute in your event handler:

```
div.setAttribute('data-before',`x: ${mousePosition.x}, y: ${mousePosition.y}`);
```

Working snippet:

```js
  var mousePosition;
  var offset = [0, 0];
  var div;
  var isDown = false;

  div = document.createElement("div");

  div.className = "display_object";
  div.innerHTML = "Draggable box:  ";

  document.body.appendChild(div);

  div.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    isDown = true;
    offset = [
      div.offsetLeft - e.clientX,
      div.offsetTop - e.clientY
    ];
  }, true);

  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    isDown = false;
  }, true);

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (isDown) {

    mousePosition = {

      x: event.clientX,
      y: event.clientY

    };

    div.style.left = (mousePosition.x + offset[0]) + 'px';
    div.style.top = (mousePosition.y + offset[1]) + 'px';

   div.setAttribute('data-before',`x: ${mousePosition.x}, y: ${mousePosition.y}`);

  }
  }, true)
  ;
```

```css
.display_object {
  position: absolute;
  border: thin solid black;
  width: 15cm;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.display_object:active::before {
  content: attr(data-before);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
  padding: 1em 3em;
  color: white;
  font-size: .8em;
  bottom: 1.6em;
  left: -1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Awesome.  Works great in the snippet and fiddle.  I'll implement it into the actual project and if it works the same then the answer is yours.